# Find and replace text with values from a list/database

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I've created a fairly simple script which finds English and replaces it with Spanish words.

```
function translatesp() {
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
.getBody();

body.replaceText('Master Change Log', 'Historial de Cambios');
body.replaceText('Prepared for:', 'Preparado para:'); 
body.replaceText('Git Reference', 'Referencia Git');

}
```

What I would like to do is have a list somewhere (probably on a separate google sheet) with all of my English and Spanish words in columns, and then change my script to look for everything in the English column and then replace it with the relevant Spanish entry, so that I don't need to keep adding vocabulary to script itself. How would one go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the translate API?

Comment: The reason I'm writing this script is because Google translate is terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually had to do basically this exact thing a while back. I ended up making a helper utility to represent spreadsheets as database tables. I put it on github here:

https://github.com/anderspitman/google-apps-script-database

Copy and paste that file into your script project then use something like the following to use it:

```
function main() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SPREADSHEET_ID_HERE');
  var translationDb = Database.fromSpreadsheet(spreadsheet)
    .getTable('Sheet1');

  var wordInAllLanguages = translationDb.findOne({ English: 'Yes' });

  Logger.log(wordInAllLanguages.Spanish);
}
```

The spreadsheet looks like this:

[image]

Note that Database class is useful for lots of other things as well. Take a look through the code to see the other functions. It's designed to be somewhat similar to interfacing with MongoDB in javascript.

Comment: This looks interesting, but from the sample bit of code that you've written here, it looks like I would still need to have a line for each bit of vocabulary, because you've written:

     `var wordInAllLanguages = translationDb.findOne({ English: 'Yes' });`

So I'm assuming I would need a line for each English word/phrase. Is this correct?

Comment: Can you add an example of how you would want it to work?

Comment: I can't seem to attach images into a comment...

Imagine the sheet that you posted has 100+ rows, what I would like is so that in the code in my OP, instead of needing to type in a whole list of find and replace terms, it could just go through the sheet, find A2 and replace with B2, find A3 and replace it with B3 and so on...

Comment: So do `var allRows = translationDb.find({})`. Then loop over allRows and for each row do `body.replaceText(row.English, row.Spanish)`